# iOS - NSMutableArray is immutable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to edit an object in NSMutable array declared in .h file and synthesised in .m file, but the app crashes with debug saying: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

The line that makes the app crash is:

```
[noteContent replaceObjectAtIndex:currentNote withObject:noteText.text];
```

`noteContent` is declared in .h `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* noteContent;`, synthesised in .m `@synthesize noteContent` and initialized in viewDidLoad

```
noteContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
noteContent = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"];
```

The problem isn't in replacing nil object, because I checked that at the position, an actual string is stored.

Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've assigned an `NSArray` to `noteContent`:

```
noteContent = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"];
```

So, while you've declared your variable to be a mutable array, the actual object being referenced is immutable. Try this:

```
noteContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"]];
```

As @Abizern explains in the comments, there is an argument to be made for doing:

```
noteContent = [[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"] mutableCopy];
```

However, it should be noted that, with this approach, `noteContent` will be `nil` if `[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"]` returns `nil`. So, if presumably you're going to be adding items to the mutable array, you would need to add more code to handle the `nil` case.

Comment: `noteContent = [[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"noteContent"] mutableCopy];` rather than `initWithArray:`, surely.

Comment: @Abizern You're probably right, but the advantages aren't immediately obvious to me. Perhaps you could expand on "surely"?

Comment: Say you have an `NSArray` object and an `NSMutableArray` object. sending `copy` to an `NSArray` will just return the `NSArray object with in incremented reference count, but sending it to an `NSMutableArray` object will return a copy of the object, but as an `NSArray` object. Sending `mutableCopy` to either will return a mutable version, regardless of whether the receiver is mutable or immutable. I say surely because a) it does the correct thing based on what the __actual__ type of the reciever is and b) It's far more readable (IMHO).

Comment: @Abizern Thanks. Seems to be a matter of style for `mutableCopy`, but your overall argument makes sense and I've added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: @Abizern updated my answer to point out that your approach would generally require additional code to handle the `nil` case.